# Set selected values in asp ListBox with one line

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to set the selected values in an asp `ListBox` webcontrol from a `string[]` but I'm getting the error

> Only assignment, call, decrement, increment and new object expressions can be used as a statement
>   Here's what I have so far...

```
string[] pageRoles = new string[] {"Admin", "Users", "Publisher"};
pageRoles.ToList().ForEach(r => rolesListBox.Items.FindByValue(r).Selected == true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is you were using a comparison operator instead of assignment.

```
string[] pageRoles = new string[] {"Admin", "Users", "Publisher"};
pageRoles.ToList().ForEach(r => rolesListBox.Items.FindByValue(r).Selected = true);
```

Comment: WOW! it's getting late, Thanks Matt :)